# parse json in object flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to parse my json in Theme object :

RESULT :

**["[\"1\",\"Alternant\"]","[\"2\",\"DevOps\"]"]**

Method getListTheme :

```
Future<List<String>> getListTheme() async {
    List<String> themes = List<String>();
    final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in preferences.getKeys()) {
      if (key == 'token') {
        preferences.containsKey(key);
      } else {
        themes.add(jsonEncode(preferences.getStringList(key)));
      }
    }
    return themes;
  }
```

Other code :

```
await Theme().getListTheme().then((value){
      theme = jsonEncode(value);
    });
```

My theme class :

```
class Theme {
  int id;
  String name;

  Theme({this.id, this.name});

  factory Theme.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Theme(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

How i can parse the result in theme object ?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: ["[\"1\",\"Alternant\"]","[\"2\",\"DevOps\"]"]

I want parse this in object theme with id/name @AndresCastro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try return a object passing the JSON like this

```
Future<Theme> fechDataTheme(){

   Theme theme  =  Theme.fromJson('YOUR JSON HERE');

   return theme;

 }
```

once you have the object you can use a FutureBuilder to get it on UI

```
FutureBuilder<Theme>(
        future: fetchDataTheme(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {


            if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(

              children: <Widget>[
                Text(snapshot.data.id),
                Text(snapshot.data.name),
              ],

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this site to convert json to dart object
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/